# How to create a threshold based on a classification model?

Tags: r, classification, biostatistics, threshold

I have a data-set that is comparing two groups (Injury only (baseline) and Surgical Modification) across multiple injury severity values (Peak Force).

Reference scatter plot for context:

[image]

BBB score - yaxis is what is defined and measured for 'neurological recovery' (categorical).
Peak Force - xaxis is various injury severity across subjects (continuous).

The goal is to come up with a model, type of analysis that tries to define the threshold injury severity (x-axis) that shows no improvement of neurological recovery (BBB score - yaxis) that is seen with surgical decompression (Duorotomy/Piotomy).

Some sort of classification model may be needed but am unsure if that is the best way to establish 'the threshold'.

### UPDATE

I decided to leverage decision tree approach to help determine a cutoff point for  surgical decompression influence on recovery (BBB).

Summary  of Data:

```
Group    Peak_Force         Recovery 
 D:16   Min.   : 34.16   Full    :20  
 I:21   1st Qu.: 40.51   Mild    :21  
 M:25   Median : 45.39   Moderate:21  
        Mean   : 52.39                
        3rd Qu.: 60.91                
        Max.   :106.31
```

Reference figure below:
[image]

The model itself is  not  that great (~ 46% accuracy).  Here  is the raw data/code that follows the plot:

```
# Drop variables
clean_df <- df %>%
  mutate(tertiles = ntile(Week_8_BBB, 3)) %>%
  mutate(Recovery = if_else(tertiles == 1, 'Mild', if_else(tertiles == 2, 'Moderate', 'Full'))) %>%
  na.omit()




clean_df <- clean_df %>%
  select(-c(tertiles, Week_1_BBB, Week_5_BBB, Week_8_BBB))


clean_df$Group <- as.factor(clean_df$Group) 
clean_df$Recovery <- as.factor(clean_df$Recovery)


## Create train/test dataset ##


create_train_test <- function(data, size = 0.8, train = TRUE) {
  n_row = nrow(data)
  total_row = size * n_row
  train_sample <- 1:total_row
  if (train == TRUE) {
    return (data[train_sample, ])
  } else {
    return (data[-train_sample, ])
  }
}

data_train <- create_train_test(clean_df, 0.8, train = TRUE)
data_test <- create_train_test(clean_df, 0.8, train = FALSE)

dim(data_train)
dim(data_test)


prop.table(table(data_train$Group))
prop.table(table(data_test$Group))


## Build Model ## 

fit <- rpart(Recovery ~., data = data_train, method = 'class')
rpart.plot(fit, # middle graph
           extra = 105, # show fitted class, probs, percentages
           box.palette = "GnBu", # color scheme
           branch.lty = 3, # dotted branch lines
           shadow.col = "gray", # shadows under the node boxes
           nn = TRUE) # display the node numbers

rpart.rules(fit, cover = TRUE)




## Prediction ##

predict_unseen <- predict(fit, data_test, type = 'class')

table_mat <- table(data_test$Recovery, predict_unseen)

table_mat


accuracy_Test <- sum(diag(table_mat)) / sum(table_mat)*100


print(paste('Accuracy for test', accuracy_Test))
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that surgery (red) has a greater mean BBB value below a peak force of 46.  It also appears that the BBB values for red and blue treatments swap above a peak force of 46, so the effect is a change it's not really a classification problem.  If you ran linear regression and regressed BBB on peakforce and used a dummy (0,1) variable for treatment (0-baseline, 1-surgery), and added an interaction term for peakforce*treatment, then perhaps the interaction variable would be significant.  This is similar to the idea of an interaction for which age increases with S.B.P. but males and females have opposite slopes.

For plotting, turn your data on it's head, and plot the index (number) of the subjects on the x-axis (baseline first, then surgery), and then plot two lines for the two y-variables: BBB and peak force.

Saying "classification" implies that some outcome is categorical (discrete), but BBB is quantitative, so you are running function approximation and happen to be interested in a cutpoint value of peak force at which the change in BBB due to treatment can be discerned.

There are many things which I could suggest you to use, but you have any classes per se, only categorical treatment which is an input experimental control variable.  You output is continuous (quantitative), and it seems like you are interested in identifying the peak force value where BBB scores change appreciably between treatment.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response - it is very helpful. To give more context, which may or may not help you better recommend a method/approach - BBB is a categorical variable (range from 0-21 with 21 being the peak and 0 being the min). BBB is locomotion test used to measure overall recovery after injury. That is why I was leaning towards a classification model. For example: BBB in a healthy subject is 21, but 10 is not half as good as 20 - bc the scale/values are not in a linear relation to another - which is why a linear reg may not be best. Goal is to compare peak force to BBB.

Comment: okay, then making think about subtracting 10 from BBB since below 10 there are no values.   But for a "10-class problem", you don't have a lot of data.  Maybe consider using a decision tree classifier (CART) with 2 feature inputs: peak force, and treatment(0,1) or 1,2.  Use the BBB classes as the class feature.  Consider collapsing classes into maybe 4, instead of 10, as 10 would result in an ill-conditioned problem (sparseness due to empty classes).   You could also binarize BBB (low, high --> 2 classes) or cut it into tertiles (low,med,high -->3 classes).

Comment: Since BBB is a severity score, you could also use it as a quantitative outcome in regression.  Likert scale scores (1-strongly disagree, 2-disagree,3-neutral, 4-agree, 5-strongly agree) are analyzed as continuous variables --> avg, s.d., a lot in pscyhometrics.

Comment: okay - I agree with that approach. I will try and mock up the model and update this with output to see if the model if a good classifier to determine what threshold works for each group. Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: My Pleasure to help out.

Comment: I updated the analysis  and included  results. I leveraged your suggestion in grouping BBB scores into "recovery" - mild, moderate, and full. I'm not too confident on the results but wanted to show you what I got.